# I want to access the localhost on PC from my mobile phone but it doesn't work

Tags: android, html, xampp, remote-access

I want to access my localhost on PC from a mobile phone. I have Windows XP and HUAWEI SNE-LX1. I run XAMPP and I connected my mobile phone by USB cable. I did it some time ago and it worked. I do the same now and it doesn't work . I am working on a website on my PC and I want to take a look to see how the website looks like on mobile phone. After connecting my mobile phone I run CMD and put ipconfig and I take the IPv4 and then  put it in the browser on mobile phone.

[image: IPv4 address]

in the browser on mobile phone the error goes: ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

[image: Firewell settings]

[image: Screen from my mobile phone]

Comment: Difficult to guess what happened. Unrelated suggestion, did you try using chrome to view multi screen, it should show you how your website looks with diff resolution and device.

Comment: yes but on the phone is more realistically i would prefer on the phone

Comment: Assuming the site works on the desktop. Did you check your firewall? Check the port is correct, Check the protocol http/https is correct.

Comment: I public another screen from my firewall settings... What do you mean when you say me to check if the port is correct?

Comment: @Olaf You need to connect to whatever service is running on a specific port. So, for instance, if you have a web server running on your computer at localhost:3000, then that same service will be accessible on your local network (assuming there are no firewall factors) at 192.168.2.100:3000 (your machine's IPv4 Address).

Comment: Why a usb cable? Why dont you use wifi?

Comment: I did everything and it stil does't work. Subir Kumar Sao what do you mean check the protocol http/https is correct? Why appears error_connection_timed_out?

Comment: It works. I can't believe. I did nothing and it started working. Thaks for helping

Answer (score 1):

This can be happening because of two things,

1. you should add port number to the address like: 192.168.2.100:5000

   where 5000 is the port number on which your app is running
2. turn off firewall of the pc/laptop

then you should be able to view the website on mobile
In my case it was the 2nd problem